# Is it possible to describe the entire universe with the behavior of an $\mathbb{R}^n$ field?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, field-theory

Suppose every phenomena in this universe (of course most are reducible to some particular general ideal ones - basically I'm talking about those!) could be described as disturbances/waves/ripples/tensions in an $\mathbb{R}^n$ field. Is this possible? Can we find $n$?

Basically, I came up with this when I studied that General theory of relativity explains gravitation as a disturbance/tension in a 4-dimensional field of space-time. Basically, I'm asking whether the entire universe can be described as such.

Answer (score 1):

Try reading up on string theory.Here is a series of lectures with ["string theory for pedestrians".](http://indico.cern.ch/conferenceDisplay.py?confId=a063319)

> A particular quantum vibration mode of the closed
>   string describes a graviton, the quantum of the
>   gravitational field. A particular quantum vibration of
>   an open string describes a photon, the quantum of the
>   electromagnetic field.
>
> In string theory all particles – matter particles and
>   force carriers – arise as quantum fluctuations of the
>   relativistic string.

One might well say that everything in the universe is described as the vibrations of some string, the entire universe. So yes, people have been working on this.